# How to print empty when data = null

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to print  " " when i get data = null.

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
var unit = $(this).find(":selected").data("product_unit");
if(unit === "null") {
  unit = "";
}
```

Comment: You want to show `" "` or just a space ` ` ?

Comment: `"null"` is a string, it is not `null` ...

Comment: console unit wheter unit is null or undefined if its null just check null

Comment: should be null instead of "null"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `"null"` to `null`. You are comparing to a string.

Also add a space to `unit = "";` to add a space if you want that.

```
var unit = $(this).find(":selected").data("product_unit");
if(unit === null) {
  unit = " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try null with out quotation marks

```
var unit = $(this).find(":selected").data("product_unit");
if(unit === null) {
  unit = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this one

```js
if (unit.trim() == '') {
  unit = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var unit = $(this).find(":selected").data("product_unit").val();
if(unit.empty()) {
  unit = "";
}
```

Comment: Welcome @test1321

Answer (score 1):

short form:

`var unit = $(this).find(":selected").data("product_unit") || "";`

if `product_unit` is a boolean `false` (false, null, empty string etc) gets overwritten to empty string

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

var unit = $(this).find(":selected").data("product_unit") || "";

Answer (score 1):

You can use .length for printing empty.

The length property returns the length of a string (number of characters).

The length of an empty string is 0.

```
var unit = $(this).find(":selected").data("product_unit");
if(unit.length === 0) {
  unit = " ";
}
```